# Automate the manual grouping process in excel by using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv

How can I automate my Manual filtering and grouping process in excel/csv by using python

Below is the data i have.

> ```
> My monthly details
> NEFT paid 100 for recharge
> RTGS paid 1000 for recharge
> Reversal Neft 100 as the provided number was wrong 
> NEFT paid 10000 for food and drinks
> RTGS received 1000000 for a personal loan
> salary received 30000
> 0000123/merchant payment
> ```

at present I am manually filtering  it and grouping it accordingly. Can i automate the process by using python.

Below is the expected outcome

> ```
> My monthly details    Remarks
> NEFT paid 100 for recharge    Neft
> RTGS paid 1000 for recharge   RTGS
> Reversal Neft 100 as the provided number was wrong    Reversal
> NEFT paid 10000 for food and drinks   NEFT
> RTGS received 1000000 for a personal loan RTGS
> salary received 30000 SALARY
> 0000123/merchant payment  fund transfer
> ```

Comment: Try [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io)

Comment: can you share me links of tutorial

Comment: http://zetcode.com/articles/openpyxl/